# Cron expression like 26-Jun to 5-Jun/every 2nd day/repeat every year

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need a cron expression which will repeat every year between two specified dates.

Ex: Run between 26-May and 7-Jun every second day and repeat every year.

I need to write something like a birthday reminder.

The best I came up with is

```
0 0 0 26-7 5-6 ? *
```

Will this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution to solve this problem with a single cron expression, so I broke it down to two different expressions.

```
0 0 0 26-31 5 ? *
```

and

```
0 0 0 1-7 6 ? *
```

Comment: that's right - because the days of the month are different for the two months, one expression can't express it.